# How to automount a usb block device with udev rule?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, udev

I want to execute 'mount -a' whenever a usb drive is connected to the computer. I have created a simple rule in the file '/etc/udev/rules.d/85-my_rule.rules':

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/bin/mount -a"
```

If I call 'sudo mount -a' manually, everything works. Using 'dmesg' I also see my drive:

```
[503534.272219] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[503534.297237] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539, bcdDevice= 1.00
[503534.297244] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[503534.297248] usb 4-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[503534.297252] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[503534.297255] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: A787E1EFFFFF
[503534.301848] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[503534.303131] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[503534.303196] scsi host8: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[503535.336866] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sharkoon  H/W RAID5            PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[503535.337941] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[503535.338353] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[503535.338589] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] 62511906816 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 TB/29.1 TiB)
[503535.339571] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[503535.339577] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[503535.340649] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
[503535.340664] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[503535.481112]  sde: sde1
[503535.484634] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

The block device is also there but the rule seems not to be executed. What should I do? I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you add the USB drive to /etc/fstab? I not `mount -a` will not mount your USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add an `ACTION` to the rule e.g.:

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mount -a"
```